# Search huge amount of entries in giant catalog of text files, python/bash

Tags: python, bash, performance, search

I need to search for around 57K entries within a catalog containing thousands of backup files, 8 Gb in total . I tried `grep -f` on a modern server but that overwhelmed the memory made the machine unresponsive . 
A normal grep for a single entry takes around 50 seconds. My next idea is to try to grep, for exemple, 100 or maybe 1000 entries at a time, but i doubt that would be fast. 
Does anyone have an idea or an example of how to do this in an efficient and fast way? I am most comfortable with bash and Python.

Comment: First, have you tried using ripgrep, or any of the other "faster grep/ack" tools out there? (If your data are in UTF-8 and you need Unicode regexps, `ripgrep` is really the only viable choice, but for simple ASCII regexps, that isn't always true, so you should check out a few of them.)

Comment: Second, is this something you're doing one time, or zillions of times? If you're doing it repeatedly, you probably want to build an index and search that. Exactly what that means depends on what the format is and what kinds of search you're trying to do. For example, full-word dictionary searches are a trivial tree search (or maybe a bloom filter in front of subtrees), while general text searches are a hard problem but with known solutions you can just drop in if you're happy with the "80% good enough" answer.

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for the suggestions. I only need to do this one time.